# I am having issues with the navigation menu when checking in IE 7 & 8

Tags: navigation, internet-explorer-7

This is the website that I am having problem with in IE 7 & 8.

http://mtcmedicalcenter.com/

The last 2 menus which are the careers and contact us are in the bottom instead of having it beside the events and promos.

Here is the css for the navigation menu.

```
/* ---------- Navigation ---------- */

#Menu{
    margin:auto;
}

#Menu #nav {
    float:left;
    z-index: 9999;
    width:auto;
    margin: -8px auto 0 auto;
}

#nav, #nav ul{
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     list-style-type:none;
     list-style-position:outside;
}

#nav ul li{
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
padding:0;
}

#nav .on {
    color: #fff !important;
    background-position: bottom left !important;
}

#nav a:link{
    display:block;
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px; /* Display: block won't work in this example, instead we are using padding to make the hole tab a clickable link */
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    background-color:#2b2f6e;
}

#nav a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#2b2f6e;
}

#nav a:visited {
    color:#fff;
}

#nav li{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    background:transparent url('../img/divider.jpg') no-repeat right;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 2px;
}
#nav ul {
    position:absolute;
    width:auto;
    display:none;   
    z-index: 1;
}

#nav li ul a {
    width:14em;
    float:left;
    background-color:#2b2f6e;
    background-repeat:repeat;
}

#nav li ul a:link{
    color:#fff;
} 

#nav li ul a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background-position: bottom left !important;
}

#nav ul li ul li a:hover{
    color:#fff !important;
    background-position: bottom left !important;
}

#nav ul ul{
    top:auto;
}   

#nav li ul ul {
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

#nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul ul{
    display:none;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    }
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li li li li:hover ul{
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    }



#nav li.current_page_item > a,
#nav li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
#nav li.current-menu-item > a,
#nav li.current-menu-parent > a {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#2b2f6e;
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
}

#nav li.services-class > a {
    color:#fff;
     background:none;   
}

.menu  #Menu li.current_page_item > a,
.menu  #Menu li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
.menu  #Menu li.current-menu-item > a,
.menu  #Menu li.current-menu-parent > a {
    color:#fff;
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:#2b2f6e;
    height: 30px;
}
```

I am using Wordpress for this website by the way. Hope to hear from you guys soon.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for a quick fix till you find a better one, you can always just set the width of the container they are in something that is wider than the content,

in your case, you can get that container by the class responsiveSelectContainer

Comment: thanks for the reply Abraham. But I don't think the container is the issue. I read some questions that has an issue about ie7 and they say something about the z-index having to do with the navigation menu. you think this is similar to that? is there a solution on that?